# Strange problem while using print's end argument in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
> python version 3.11.6
> os: Windows
> Idle: Visual studio code (Latest version)
```

My code looks something like this:

```
from time import sleep


x = [
"H",
"E",
"L",
"L",
"O"
]
for i in x:
    print(i, end="")
    sleep(.5)
```

when I run this expected output is:
H wait E wait L wait L wait O

but output is:
*A long wait* then all characters instantly.

But why?

**I noticed when I don't use end argument code works well.**

""Additional info"":
also tried using `sys.stdout.write()` same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `end=""` argument in the print function, it suppresses the newline character (`\n`) that `print` normally adds at the end of each print statement.

you can use `flush=True` argument in the `print` function, to solve this:

```
from time import sleep

x = [
    "H",
    "E",
    "L",
    "L",
    "O"
]

for i in x:
    print(i, end="", flush=True)
    sleep(.5)
```

As an alternative, you could achieve the same result by combining `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.flush()`:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

x = [
    "H",
    "E",
    "L",
    "L",
    "O"
]

for i in x:
    sys.stdout.write(i)
    sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush the output buffer
    sleep(.5)
```

Comment: Can you kindly clarify why the problem doesn't occur when we use flush=True? also why when end=""